# SharePoint bread crumbs navigation

Tags: navigation

(SharePoint 2010 site)
I have created document libraries for each menu item at the top link bar.
Document library of a particular menu title contains several folders and an aspx file of that menu item.

Folders in document library contains aspx pages of subpages of respective menu title.

So the problem is when I click on the subpage the breadcrumb appears as

"Home>Menu title>subpage"

and then when I click on menu title, it shows the contents of "Menu title"(document library), which also contains menutitle.aspx,instead of showing menutitle.aspx

so how can I change that. I want menutitle.aspx page to be opened when I click on 
Menu title(bread crumb).

Menu title document library contains menutitle.aspx and other folders that contains subpages.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the breadcrumbs by modifying the master page, and if you need to you can drive the breadcrumb from list data.

Alternatively on teh client(browser) side you can delete the HTML element and replace it with your custom breadcrumb.

We have driven bookmarks from custom lists programmatically in the past to help with global navigation (cross site-collection).

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below, if any help you can get. I have tried by modifying the master page http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/breadcrumb-in-sharepoint-2010-19.aspx